# What's the difference between "gcloud auth print-access-token" and get access token from OAuth Code Flow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a question about what's the difference between get access token from `gcloud auth print-access-token` in Google Cloud Console and get access token from **OAuth Code Flow**. Are these two type of access token related?

It because I can't assign a `scope` to the command line when generate a new access token. I wondered how many permission I will get after I got the access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing. And yes, you can't assign scope at token generation, but you can at credential creation

```
gcloud auth login --scopes=....
```